# How to push a message To A UserAdmin for each user

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I have problem to make a task in may project but i don't know how.
Sinario:
I have user1 will click on button(Help) in users space,
this button will send notification to the user2(admin),
this admin can accept to help immediatly of user1 by clicking on
button(yes for exemple) or let him wait by clicking on button(wait).
in both case notification of response will notif the user1 about the
response of the adimintrator.
you can find images discribe the idea
im using

Backend: Spring boot
DB: PostgreSql
FrontEnd: Angular
Some Suggestionss : they tell me using Websocket
is that true  ... any suggestion  i'll appreciate.

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhKKO.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfsJU.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xXXc.png)